# Google Chrome aborting after start on 21.04 with Budgie desktop - no GUI error messages

Tags: google-chrome, systemd-coredump

Chromium runs perfectly, but google-chrome fails with no error message.  Window freezes and disappears after 5 seconds.  I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

On staring google-chrome from terminal, I get the following:

```
nick@mars:~$ google-chrome
[1114/113526.814889:WARNING:process_reader_linux.cc(125)] no stack mapping
[1114/113526.823445:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1114/113526.823473:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[5834:6092:1114/113528.435275:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5834:6092:1114/113528.435303:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[5834:6092:1114/113528.435317:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5834:6092:1114/113528.475084:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I contacted Google One support, but they are not being helpful.  They blame Ubuntu updates without any specific investigation.

Grateful for any advice / suggestions!

Nick

Answer (score 1):

This was solved with version 96.0.4664.45-1 of google chrome stable released today.